# How to Render different components in fixed layout

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have created separate `sidebar`, `header` and `content` page using *react js*. but how to `render` different-pages on the `side-bar menu click` in the `same content` container

I am using this code for display menu header and a section on the main page but I am unable to open another page in the same section

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './header';
import SideBar from './menu';
import Content from './content';

class App extends Component {
render() {
return ( <div>
<Header />
<SideBar />
<Content />
</div>

);
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

For `rendering different pages (serving different routes`) in same layout .
Using `router` is a proper way of achieve that feature.

> You can use routers in any number of components you want.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <Header />
                <SideBar />
                    <div id=#content>
                        <Switch>

                            <Route path="/page1" component={page1} />

                            <Route path="/page2" component={page2} /> 

                        </Switch>
                    </div>
            </div>

            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: but i want to call page based on menu selection. I also try this its working fine. but i want to call page on menu selection not fixed in route.

Comment: In sidebar you have as many menu ..and you have to give them route ok ... On menu click routes will change but layout will be fixed only new page will tender .

Comment: @MdZafar that is the solution above  for that requirement bro . just try and understand . this is the only solution .